# Combining read and write into one query with mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have two mongodb collections **items** and **settings**.

When documents are inserted into items, one of the fields *level* needs to be read from the *settings* table. Currently I'm running two queries to make this happen.

Is there a way to do this as one query like I could do with SQL with select queries inside an insert?

```
// read
let settingRecord = connection.collection("settings").findOne({
    "group_id": 2
}, function(err, result) {});

// write
connection.collection("items").insertOne({
    "item_id": 2,
    "group_id": 2,
    "level": settingRecord['level']
  }, function(err, result) {});
```

[image]

Comment: You can do this with $merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as below using `$merge` but with some more pipelines as mentioned by @D. SM

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate( [
   { $match : { group: 2 } },
   { $project: {level: 1, group:1} },
   { $addFields:{item:2} },
   { $merge : { into: { db: "local", coll: "test2" },   whenMatched: [{ $addFields: {
                "level":"$$new.level", "group":"$$new.group", "item":"$$new.item"
                } } ] , whenNotMatched: "insert" }}
] )
```

Explanation:

```
{ $match : { group: 2 } }
```

Match on a field to get the document - In your case, it would be settings collection

```
 { $project: {level: 1, group:1} },
```

Project only the required fields to the next stage. You can skip this stage.

```
{ $addFields:{item:2} },
```

Using this you can add list of new fields to be inserted.

Actual magic happens in `$merge`

1. `into` - db and collection where data has to be inserted
2. `whenMatched` - add what fields to be inserted, `$$new` is used to refer the fields matched in the previous stage

[Refer this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#use-the-pipeline-to-customize-the-merge)

You can play with the pipelines to avoid unnecessary things. `$merge` has more options. In this example, you can skip `whenNotMatched` if you don't want to insert for non match items. You can specify to `fail` in that case.

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks so much Gibbs!! It looks like the query/insert is working. The only problem I'm debugging now is it seems it's constantly overwriting the record even when added field item_id is changing during the insert where as I'm expecting a new record created.

Comment: Do you mean different value for `item_id`?

Comment: Yes, if I change the value for item_id and re-run the query somehow it overwrites the old record inside "items" collection instead of creating a new record. I'm not sure if its somehow re-creating the whole collection as I only have one record right now.

Comment: In that case, you need to use `on` option of `$merge` which specifies on what field the operation has to be decided. I mean `whenMatched, whenNotMatched` as operations.

Comment: I see, I just added on: "item_id" but now its complaining that my _id index has a duplicate, where is it even getting that _id from for that old record.  `MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: mydb.items.index: _id_ dup key`

Comment: ah I got it! I had to add "_id" : 0 in my projection or it was trying to re-insert that same duplicate value everytime

Comment: thanks very much for your help I really appreciate the detailed explanation, mongodb is great!

Answer (score 1):

I could merge into a new collection with a merge command for the given requirement of updating the level field. Let me know how to update the same collection as in aggregate collection eg. items collection in this case.

```
> db.newCollection.find();
{ "_id" : 1, "groupid" : 2, "itemid" : 2, "settingsDoc" : [ { "level" : 10 } ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "groupid" : 3, "itemid" : 3, "settingsDoc" : [ { "level" : 30 } ] }
> db.items1.find();
{ "_id" : 1, "groupid" : 2, "itemid" : 2, "level" : null }
{ "_id" : 2, "groupid" : 3, "itemid" : 3, "level" : null }
> db.settings.find();
{ "_id" : 1, "groupid" : 2, "level" : 10 }
{ "_id" : 2, "groupid" : 3, "level" : 30 }
> db.items1.aggregate([
... {$lookup:{
...     from: "settings",
...     localField: "groupid",
...     foreignField: "groupid",
...     as:"settingsDoc"
...     }
... },
... {$project:{
...     groupid:1,
...     itemid:1,
...     "settingsDoc.level":1
...     }
... },
... {$merge:{into:"newCollection"}
... }
... ]);
> db.newCollection.find();
{ "_id" : 1, "groupid" : 2, "itemid" : 2, "settingsDoc" : [ { "level" : 10 } ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "groupid" : 3, "itemid" : 3, "settingsDoc" : [ { "level" : 30 } ] }
>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Is there a reason to use lookup versus match?

Comment: you are welcome. Since its join to other collection, lookup is used. if its subquery this is best suited as per mongo db documentation. Use match when you need a reporting kind of aggregation from same collection (eg. avg, sum ups , groups etc). hope this helps.